# Program does not display details of another controller

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I am having the following problem with the program. It allows login and logout.
When I am logged in as a partner I want to see the list of registered teachers and choose one as a personal trainer.
The program does not give errors, but when I click on the link "choose PT" it does not present me the data of the teacher I chose. I created the view of type details.
In the view of choosing PT I have:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Professores

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "EscolherPt";
}


<style>
    body {
        padding-top: 0px;
        background-color: gray;
        background-image: url();
        background-image: url();
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <h4 style="color : red">Tem a certeza que deseja solicitar este personal trainer ? </h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telefone)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telefone)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Fotografia)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            <img src="~/Fotos/ + model.Fotografia " />

        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sexo)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @if (@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sexo) == "true")
            {
                <p>Feminino</p>
            }
            else
            {
                <p>Masculino</p>
            }
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Especialidade)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Especialidade)
        </dd>
        @*<dt class = "col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Estado)
            </dt>
            <dd class = "col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Estado)
            </dd>
            <dt class = "col-sm-2">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
            </dt>
            <dd class = "col-sm-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Password)
            </dd>*@
    </dl>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Solicitar" class="btn btn-primary" />
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />
```

In the Teachers controller I have the method

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> EscolherPt(int? id)
        {


            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var professores = await _context.Professores
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Idprofessor == id);
            if (professores == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View();
        }
```

I am logged in as a partner trying to access the details of a specific teacher,
By pressing submit I want him to become my personal trainer.
Social class :

```
 public partial class Socios
    {
        public Socios()
        {
            Gerir = new HashSet<Gerir>();
            Mensagem = new HashSet<Mensagem>();
            Participa = new HashSet<Participa>();
            PersonalTrainer = new HashSet<PersonalTrainer>();
            Peso = new HashSet<Peso>();
            PlanosExercicios = new HashSet<PlanosExercicios>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("IDSocio")]
        public int Idsocio { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("email")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("telefone")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("fotografia")]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string Fotografia { get; set; }
        [Column("sexo")]
        public bool Sexo { get; set; } // true- Feminino
                                      //  false" - Masculino
        [Column("altura")]
        public double Altura { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("nome_utilizador")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string NomeUtilizador { get; set; }
        [Column("peso_inicial")]
        public double PesoInicial { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("_password")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Column("estado")]
        public int Estado { get; set; } // 1 ativo, 0 suspenso 

        //[Column("mensalidade")]
        //public bool Mensalidade { get; set; } //0-nao pago  1-pago

        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Gerir> Gerir { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Mensagem> Mensagem { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Participa> Participa { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalTrainer> PersonalTrainer { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Peso> Peso { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdsocioNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PlanosExercicios> PlanosExercicios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Class teachers

```
public partial class Professores
    {
        public Professores()
        {
            MapaAulasGrupo = new HashSet<MapaAulasGrupo>();
            Mensagem = new HashSet<Mensagem>();
            PersonalTrainer = new HashSet<PersonalTrainer>();
            Peso = new HashSet<Peso>();
            PlanosExercicios = new HashSet<PlanosExercicios>();
        }

        [Key]
        [Column("IDProfessor")]
        public int Idprofessor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("nome")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("email")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Column("telefone")]
        public int Telefone { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("fotografia")]

        public string Fotografia { get; set; }
        [Column("sexo")]
        public bool Sexo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("especialidade")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Especialidade { get; set; }
        [Column("estado")]
        public int Estado { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column("_password")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<MapaAulasGrupo> MapaAulasGrupo { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Mensagem> Mensagem { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalTrainer> PersonalTrainer { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<Peso> Peso { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdprofessorNavigation")]
        public virtual ICollection<PlanosExercicios> PlanosExercicios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Personal Trainer Class (PT)

```
[Table("Personal_trainer")]
    public partial class PersonalTrainer
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("IDProfessor")]
        public int Idprofessor { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column("IDSocio")]
        public int Idsocio { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column("Data_Pedido", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime DataPedido { get; set; }
        [Column("data_Inicio", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }
        [Column("data_fim", TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Idprofessor))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Professores.PersonalTrainer))]
        public virtual Professores IdprofessorNavigation { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(Idsocio))]
        [InverseProperty(nameof(Socios.PersonalTrainer))]
        public virtual Socios IdsocioNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to show the details of a teacher chosen from a list?
I tried to do so so that the selected teacher becomes the partner's personaltrainer.

```
public IActionResult EscolherPT(PersonalTrainer personalTrainer, Socios socio, Professores professores)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("UserId"));


    foreach (var item in _context.Socios)
    {
        if (item.Idsocio == x)
        {
            var y = item;
            return View(y);

        }
    }
    personalTrainer.DataInicio = DateTime.Now;
    personalTrainer.Idsocio = socio.Idsocio;

    foreach (var item in _context.Socios)
    {
        if (item.NomeUtilizador == User.Identity.Name)
        {
            personalTrainer.Idsocio = item.Idsocio;
            personalTrainer.Idprofessor = professores.Idprofessor;
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this

```
return View();
```

You have to return the filled model to the view like this:

```
return View(personalTrainer);
```

take this page [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) as an example.